# RecyclerView: Heavy computing leads to incorrectly named or doubled files inside RV (With Video)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

since a long time now, I am having the same issue over and over with the recyclerview.

The short version of this: When the RV is scrolling quickly and need to do a lot of computing in short time, it sometimes just "skips" lines of  code.

I have videotaped this behaviour in this 10-sec video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVAvY6X5yr0.

Notice how I am scrolling down to the song file "Supreme". It is said to be by Billy Talent which it isn't. It is actually by Robbie Williams. And the RV does in fact know this. 
When I scroll down until the views are way off the screen and then scroll back up, it seems to have "corrected" itself. The song is now by Robbie Williams. Also, the incorrect album cover art to the left of it is now also fixed and it shows the standart image, since there was never an album cover art on my phone.

When scrolling becomes very intens, the results are getting worse and worse. Sometimes items double or even tripple, while when clicked on the right song is being played.

Also interessting that the RV picked out the correct song name: "Supreme" but messed up the album cover art and the artist name.

Another thing worth noting: Every album cover art is supposed to be cropped into the same circle. However, the incorrect album cover art for "Supreme" is simple ignored and left into its rectangular form. Again: As if the RV is just "skipping" lines of code.

Well, speaking of it: this is basically the whole thing:

The Init function, called from OnCreate():

```
    private void InitRecView()
    {

        ImageView lnBg = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.background_recView);

        mAdapter = new PhotoAlbumAdapter(GetSortedListWithAllSongs(), this, dbSeekObj, seekObj, mAudioManager, this, lnBg);

        // Get our RecyclerView layout:
        mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

        // Plug the adapter into the RecyclerView:
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.SetItemViewCacheSize(50);
        mRecyclerView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
        mRecyclerView.DrawingCacheQuality = DrawingCacheQuality.High;

        mLayoutManager = new PreCachingLayoutManager(this);
        mLayoutManager.ItemPrefetchEnabled = true;
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    }
```

The PhotoViewHolder:

```
public class PhotoViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
        public TextView SongName { get; private set; }
        public LinearLayout lnContainer { get; private set; }
        public TextView AristName { get; private set; }
        public ImageButton CoverArt { get; private set; }
        public Drawable dr { get; set; }


        public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView, List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj, Activity_Player act, MediaMetadataRetriever reader, DataBase db, List<SeekObj> seekObj, AudioManager audioManager, ImageView lnBg, Context ctx) : base(itemView)
        {
            // Locate and cache view references:
            SongName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
            AristName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            lnContainer = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linlay_cardview);
            CoverArt = itemView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.musical_note);

            this.mp3Obj = mp3Obj;
            this.act = act;
            this.reader = reader;
            this.db = db;
            this.seekObj = seekObj;
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.audioManager = audioManager;
            this.lnBg = lnBg;


            lnContainer.Click += delegate
            {
                int pos = AdapterPosition;
                ClickEvent(pos, AristName.Text, SongName.Text, CoverArt, lnBg);
            };
        }

        private void ClickEvent(int position, string artist, string song, ImageView CoverArt, ImageView lnBackground)
        {

            if (PhotoAlbumAdapter.NewSongUri != null)
            {
                PhotoAlbumAdapter.OldSongUri = PhotoAlbumAdapter.NewSongUri;
            }

            PhotoAlbumAdapter.NewSongUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mp3Obj[position].Mp3Uri);

            if (!FirstStart) // dont save the very first uri, only get it for playing 
            {
                ObjectToBeSaved = WriteMetaDataToFileList(PhotoAlbumAdapter.OldSongUri.ToString());
            }

            Activity_Player.CurrentSongObject = WriteMetaDataToFileList(PhotoAlbumAdapter.NewSongUri.ToString());
            Activity_Player.txt_CurrentSong.Text = song;
            Activity_Player.txt_CurrentArtist.Text = artist;

            PlayMusic(PhotoAlbumAdapter.NewSongUri);

            FirstStart = false;

            Activity_Player.SetBackgroundToHeader(dr, lnBg, Activity_Player.btn_Settings, ctx);

        }
```

And the probably most important class, 
the PhotoAlbumAdapter:

```
 public class PhotoAlbumAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
        {
            public List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj;
            Context ctx;
            Activity_Player act;
            MediaMetadataRetriever reader;
            DataBase db;
            List<SeekObj> seekObj;
            Typeface tf;
            AudioManager audioManager;
            ImageView lnBg;
            LinearLayout ln;

            public static Android.Net.Uri NewSongUri = null;
            public static Android.Net.Uri OldSongUri = null;

            public PhotoAlbumAdapter(List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj, Context ctx, DataBase db, List<SeekObj> seekObj, AudioManager audioManager, Activity_Player act, ImageView lnBg)
            {
                this.lnBg = lnBg;
                this.mp3Obj = mp3Obj;
                this.ctx = ctx;
                this.db = db;
                this.seekObj = seekObj;
                this.act = act;
                this.audioManager = audioManager;

                reader = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

                tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(ctx.Assets, "Baiti.ttf");
            }

            public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.CardView, parent, false);
                PhotoViewHolder vh = new PhotoViewHolder(itemView, mp3Obj, act, reader, db, seekObj, audioManager, lnBg, ctx);

                ln = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linlay_album_art);
                ln.LayoutParameters.Height = ctx.Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / 10;
                ln.RequestLayout();

                return vh;
            }

            public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
            {
                PhotoViewHolder vh = holder as PhotoViewHolder;
                SetContent(vh, position);

            }

            public override void OnViewRecycled(Java.Lang.Object holder)
            {
                base.OnViewRecycled(holder);

            }

            private async void SetContent(PhotoViewHolder vh, int position)        {
                await SetContentAsync(vh, position);
            }

            private async Task SetContentAsync(PhotoViewHolder vh, int position)
            {
                string SongName = "";
                string ArtistName = "";
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                byte[] data = null;
                RequestOptions requestOptions = null;

                try
                {
                    reader.SetDataSource(mp3Obj[position].Mp3Uri);
                }
                catch { }


                await Task.Run(() => // cause problems with the reload
                {
                    SongName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle);
                    ArtistName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist);

                    data = reader.GetEmbeddedPicture();

                    if (data != null)
                    {
                      //  try
                      //  {
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);

                            requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                            requestOptions.InvokeDiskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.None);
                           // requestOptions.SkipMemoryCache(true);
                            requestOptions.CircleCrop();
                            requestOptions.CenterInside();
                            requestOptions.FitCenter();
                            requestOptions.OptionalCircleCrop();


                            ConvertBitmapToBackground(bitmap, vh, data); // Set As Backgorund, blurry and black ( just sets the variable)

                       // }
                       // catch { }
                    }

                });



                ((Activity)ctx).RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    vh.SongName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                    vh.AristName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                    vh.SongName.Text = SongName;
                    vh.AristName.Text = ArtistName;

                  //  try
                  //  {
                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            Glide
                                 .With(ctx)
                                 .Load(data)
                                 .Apply(requestOptions)
                                 .Into(vh.CoverArt);


                        }
                        else // because recycler items inherit their shit and if it is altered it just shows views were there shouldnt be any ... 
                        {
                            vh.CoverArt.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_musicalnote);
                            vh.dr = null;
                        }
                   // }
                   // catch { }

                });


            }

            public override int ItemCount
            {

                get
                {
                    if (mp3Obj != null)
                    {
                        return mp3Obj.Count();
                    }
                    else
                        return 0;
                }
            }    

        }

        }
```

In SetContentAsync() is where the RV deceides where to put what item to. This is where I am clearly stating what it is supposed to do and this is where I believe lines of code are getting skipped.

I really, really need help here. I think I am doing everything right - can anyone explain this odd behavior?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the issue you have with the name and album could be caused by `MediaMetaDateRetriever`, if the songs are on the device you can use MediaStore. With the image, set a placeholder..

Comment: Thank you, but it cannot be that since with stoppoints i have seen it handing over the correct values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the Async processing is likely to blame. Sometimes you may have one iteration completing before one that was initiated earlier which essentially allows the earlier one to overwrite the later "correct" values.

To counter this, I would place a UUID flag in each holder before you initiate the async operation and only allow the view to be updated if the flags match once the async operation completes. This would ensure that the "stale" operations are not capable of updating the UI.

Comment: sounds likeley. can you give me  an example of this "UUID" flag? that be awesome :)

Comment: Just generate a random UUID and place it in your viewholder before starting the async op.  Check the viewholder still has the same UUID value before updating the data in it.  If another iteration has started for the same viewholder, the UUID would have changed.

Comment: hello again. it looks like the async task has actually been causing this issue. I will see if I am going to be able to fix this with the UUID flag!